# typeahead autocomplete for Django

Tags: django, django-views, bootstrap-typeahead

**base.html**

```
<html lang=en>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/media/js/autocomplete.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/dimensions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/autocomplete.js"></script>
    {% block extra_css %}{% endblock extra_css %}
    <title>{% block title %}books are social{% endblock title %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock body %}
  </body>
</html>
```

and the smaller template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function(){
  setAutoComplete("bookSearchField", "bookResults", "/lookup/?query=");
});
</script>
<label for="bookSearchField">Book: </label>
<input type="text" id="bookSearchField" name="bookSearchField">
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
urlpatterns = patterns('project.app.views',
    (r'^/lookup/$', 'book_lookup'),
)
```

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from django.http import HttpResponse
from project.app.models import Book
def book_lookup(request):
    # Default return list
    results = []
    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.GET.has_key(u'query'):
            value = request.GET[u'query']
            # Ignore queries shorter than length 3
            if len(value) > 2:
                model_results = Book.objects.filter(name__icontains=value)
                results = [ {x.id :x.name,} for x in model_results ]
    json = simplejson.dumps(results)
    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
```

so is there any tutorial/solution to create bootstrap typeahead for elagent and responsive .

```
<input id="book_lookup" class="search-query typeahead" data-items="4" type="text"

                        placeholder="Select here....">
```

**Edited:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var typeahead_data = [];
        function get_client_names() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/lookup/?query=",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        typeahead_data.push(value.toString());
                    });
                    // assign the array to my typeahead tag
                    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
                        source: typeahead_data,
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    $(function () {
        get_client_names();
    });
</script>
```

**need something like**

```
 $("#book_lookup").tokenInput([{"id": 1, "name": "ddddd"},{"id": 2, "name": "ddffddd"}],{preventDuplicates: true,
            hintText: "Type book name here...",
            validateInputAjax: true,
            validateInputObjectType: "book name",
            validateInputNewObjectLink: function (value) {
                                          $('#book_lookup').tokenInput(
                                    'add', {'id': value, 'name': value});
                                          return true;
                                        },
            validateInput: function (value) {
                 $.post("/lookup/", {validate_field_name: value},
                        function(data){
                         if (data.valid) {
                          $("#book_lookup").tokenInput('valid', value);
                         } else {
                          $("#book_lookup").tokenInput('invalid', value, 'is not a valid Book name');
                         };
                 });
          }});
          });
```

how to change data-source to book_lookup json view  ?

Comment: Just try `data-source='/lookup/'`

Comment: /lookup/?query=

has a key called 'query' .  So ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Bootstrap's typeahead before and what I did was create a method to get the dictionary via Ajax like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var typeahead_data = [];
        function get_client_names() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/lookup",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        typeahead_data.push(value.toString());
                    });
                    // assign the array to my typeahead tag
                    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
                        source: typeahead_data,
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    $(function () {
        get_client_names();
    });
</script>
```

The tag element is like this:

```
<input id="book_lookup" class="search-query typeahead" data-items="4" type="text"
                        placeholder="Select here....">
```

And basically the rest of your code is ok.

Note that here you're doing an ajax request (**this requeires jquery**) to the `/lookup/` view which in turn returns a json object, that should look like this: `[name1,name2,name3...]`. You can test if the view is working ok by just accessing the view through the explorer like this: /lookup/ and if you see the dictionary displaying correctly there, the server side is ok.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: hi @Paulo Bu . but i need to get the id of the name too . then only i can process the form . :)  . if request is_ajax(): # is needed? instead of if request.method == "GET":

Comment: Ok, mine answer doesn't answers the question out of the box, I just tried to make a point on how to use bootstrap with ajax. If you need to get the Id as well, you'll get a Javascript dictionary instead of an array and hence you'll have to treat it that way. `is_ajax()` not needed, `$.ajax` make the request with method `GET` as default.

Answer (score 1):

In Paulo's answer, he just has a static list of items to search from, that is why he calls the ajax on load, and gets the list and adds it to the source.

In your case, I think, you need to query whatever the user types, and send it to the server. This can be done by adding the function param in data-source, which gets 2 arguments, query and a callback.

[Check here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead)